# the blue line of the timeline doesnt match with my current frame

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

[image]

The blue bar doesn't match with the blue line, and when I press play the blue line also goes in a very slow way

It's impossible for me to insert keyframes, because if I insert a 1s animation, it is actually longer than that.

Answer (score 5):

In the *Output* panel, you must have played with the *Dimensions > Time Remapping* values (which are used to slow down or speed up the animation), bring them back to 100/100 for example:

[image]

Comment: +1 for obscurity :)

Comment: "obscurity"? what do you mean?

Comment: The problem is so unusual. It would have taken me ages to track it down :)

Comment: oh ok, but once you've used Time Remapping you'll remember that it desyncrhonizes the cursor with the line

Comment: Ahh, OK. I prefer messing about in the NLA.

Comment: Yes it's cleaner to do it through the dopesheet or graph editor but time remapping is faster and it allows to test some speed changes, plus sometimes you can't move some animations together

Comment: damn, you saved my ass, I just remember I adjusted it when I making some particles.thx!!!!!